# Stacked bars chart not rendering on mobile

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this stacked bars chart which works fine on desktop but it suddenly stopped rendering on mobile, you can see it on this link [here](https://www.menacorona.com)

here is a working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kamel3d/bh78odsf/)

I post the code here again since Stackoverflow is asking me to do so, it also asked me to add more text since it thinks my question is mostly code so I have to add more words you might not necessarily need or find it useful to answer this question, you could go to the website and see the code live there or click on the link on JSfiddle they are both reproduction of a working example with the issue I mentioned earlier, I think I have to stop adding more words now.

```
    var seriesColors = [
                                        '#fb6e4c',
                                        '#5f7aec',
                                        '#fde46f',
                                        '#6cb8f4',
                                        '#8ee4a0',
                                        '#e373f7'
                                        ];    

                var chart = new Highcharts.chart('mychart', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        spacingLeft: 35,
                        // plotBackgroundColor: '#bcbcbc',
                        marginBottom: 60,
                     },
                    title: false,
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ["  1 مارس 2020","  2 مارس 2020","  3 مارس 2020","  4 مارس 2020","  5 مارس 2020","  6 مارس 2020","  7 مارس 2020","  8 مارس 2020","  9 مارس 2020","  10 مارس 2020","  11 مارس 2020","  12 مارس 2020","  13 مارس 2020","  14 مارس 2020","  15 مارس 2020","  16 مارس 2020","  17 مارس 2020","  18 مارس 2020","  19 مارس 2020","  20 مارس 2020","  21 مارس 2020","  22 مارس 2020","  23 مارس 2020","  24 مارس 2020","  25 مارس 2020","  26 مارس 2020","  27 مارس 2020","  28 مارس 2020","  29 مارس 2020","  30 مارس 2020","  31 مارس 2020","  1 أبريل 2020","  2 أبريل 2020","  3 أبريل 2020","  4 أبريل 2020","  5 أبريل 2020","  6 أبريل 2020","  7 أبريل 2020","  8 أبريل 2020","  9 أبريل 2020","  10 أبريل 2020","  11 أبريل 2020","  12 أبريل 2020","  13 أبريل 2020","  14 أبريل 2020","  15 أبريل 2020","  16 أبريل 2020","  17 أبريل 2020","  18 أبريل 2020","  19 أبريل 2020","  20 أبريل 2020","  21 أبريل 2020","  22 أبريل 2020","  23 أبريل 2020","  24 أبريل 2020","  25 أبريل 2020","  26 أبريل 2020","  27 أبريل 2020","  28 أبريل 2020","  29 أبريل 2020","  30 أبريل 2020","  1 مايو 2020","  2 مايو 2020","  3 مايو 2020","  4 مايو 2020","  5 مايو 2020","  6 مايو 2020","  7 مايو 2020","  8 مايو 2020","  9 مايو 2020","  10 مايو 2020","  11 مايو 2020","  12 مايو 2020","  13 مايو 2020","  14 مايو 2020","  15 مايو 2020","  16 مايو 2020","  17 مايو 2020","  18 مايو 2020","  19 مايو 2020","  20 مايو 2020","  21 مايو 2020","  22 مايو 2020","  23 مايو 2020","  24 مايو 2020","  25 مايو 2020","  26 مايو 2020","  27 مايو 2020","  28 مايو 2020","  29 مايو 2020","  30 مايو 2020","  31 مايو 2020","  1 يونيو 2020","  2 يونيو 2020","  3 يونيو 2020","  4 يونيو 2020","  5 يونيو 2020","  6 يونيو 2020","  7 يونيو 2020","  8 يونيو 2020","  9 يونيو 2020","  10 يونيو 2020","  11 يونيو 2020","  12 يونيو 2020","  13 يونيو 2020","  14 يونيو 2020","  15 يونيو 2020","  16 يونيو 2020","  17 يونيو 2020",],
                        labels:{
                                useHTML:true,
                                formatter:function(){return '<span class="xlabel">' + this.value + '</span>';},
                                enabled:true,//default is true,
                                step: 15,
                               // rotation: -90,
                                // style: {
                                //     color: '#eb583b',
                                //     font: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                                //     fontSize: '20px',
                                //     rtl: true,
                                //     },
                                 },
                        //       itemStyle: {
                        //     color: '#6c757d',
                        //     fontSize: '15px',
                        //     fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                        //     // direction: 'rtl'
                        //                 },

                    },
                    yAxis: {


                        labels:{
                            format:"{value:,.0f}"

                        },
                        opposite: true,
                        min: 0,
                        title: false,
                        stackLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                color: ( // theme
                                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                                ) || 'gray'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        align: 'center',
                        x: 0,
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: -10,
                        floating: false,
                        backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
                        rtl: true,
                        borderColor: '#CCC',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        shadow: false,
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: '#6c757d',
                            fontSize: '15px',
                            fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                            // direction: 'rtl'
                        },

                    },
                    tooltip: {   
                        borderColor:'grey',                  
                        shared: true,
                        useHTML: true,
                        style: {fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'"},
                        // headerFormat: '<b><span class="tooltiphead">{point.x}</span></b>',
                        //  pointFormat: '<br/>{point.y:,.0f} :{series.name}',
                        //  footerFormat: '</br><span>{point.stackTotal:,.0f} :الإجمالي</span>'
                         formatter: function() {
                            var s = '<b><span class="tooltiphead">'+ this.x +'</span></b>';
                            sum = 0;
                            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                            s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name + ':  '+ numberWithCommas(point.y) +' <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:'+ point.color +';"></i>';
                            sum += point.y;
                                });
                                s += '<br/><b>الإجمالي: '+ numberWithCommas(sum)+'</b>'
                            return s;
                        },
                    },
                    plotOptions: {

                        column: {
                            // pointPadding: 0,
                            // borderWidth: 0,
                            // groupPadding: 0,
                            // shadow: false,
                            maxPointWidth: 50,
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                        },
                        series: {// this i snot working you can delete it is you come back later 
                            pointPlacement:'between',
                                grouping: false,
                                // pointWidth:9.5,
                                groupPadding: 0,
                                pointPadding: 0.12,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                animation: false,
                                states: {
                                        hover:{
                                            // color: '#bcbcbc',
                                        },
                                        inactive: {
                                                        enabled: true,
                                                        opacity: 0.5
                                                  }
                                     },

                                },

                    },
                    series: [
                     {
                        name: 'أمريكا الشمالية',
                        data: [1600,1376,1866,1234,1281,2043,1747,1221,875,1195,1760,1567,1581,1916,1940,1630,2020,1999,2368,2364,2731,3186,3098,3722,5381,5490,7058,7352,7346,7001,8789,8545,9287,8646,8945,9324,10646,9481,9573,10316,11347,11893,11671,11828,11131,11452,12746,12805,11946,13001,12500,14228,11946,13577,13141,12266,11585,11505,11437,12531,13080,13454,12037,12910,14026,14353,16734,14588,16332,16083,17859,16089,18346,17721,18079,20507,18580,20217,20941,21890,22289,23821,25110,23981,24292,22219,20086,23277,25056,29193,27037,29279,26993,30444,32656,33103,32132,34318,34793,35873,31253,33154,37926,37140,39329,38987,39512,37157,37330,],
                       color: seriesColors[0]
                    }, {           
                        name: 'أوروبا',
                        data: [737,527,629,979,1401,1775,2137,2544,2782,3405,5059,7410,7433,8189,8383,10754,11123,13635,18360,20475,21446,19083,25434,23619,29674,34985,35590,36517,29442,30888,35147,36524,35560,37105,33515,29825,27118,29006,34532,33346,38600,30544,52732,25738,26085,31304,43302,32784,23983,35559,24326,26815,26674,29006,25403,26027,23139,23518,23099,21547,23762,23687,24624,22495,21623,23081,28696,26725,25694,22499,21522,24137,21931,19808,21099,21380,18715,18252,16699,18441,15417,17602,19788,17827,15741,14566,18225,15184,20382,17077,17337,15604,14113,14735,20582,15995,16873,16805,15669,14885,14468,14928,14351,15486,16241,15477,15050,13612,15122,],
                       color: seriesColors[1]
                    },{
                        name: 'آسيا',
                        data: [1,4,3,10,3,19,0,40,8,13,15,28,35,78,61,89,84,122,182,205,221,288,401,467,540,577,583,391,561,470,620,633,701,906,698,733,706,666,804,830,691,725,867,797,973,954,1187,1427,1320,1227,1173,1097,1417,1452,1735,1262,1555,1335,1686,2017,2092,1752,2203,1646,2695,2091,2547,2607,3805,2861,2767,3033,3207,2988,3029,2929,3432,3018,3699,3358,3761,4798,4161,3875,4131,4106,3590,5291,4749,5957,6225,5195,5943,4931,5147,7198,7154,6659,6122,6882,6882,6530,6489,7255,8255,8105,8838,9636,7367,],
                       color: seriesColors[2]
                    },{
                        name: 'أمريكا الجنوبية',
                        data: [12,27,23,37,74,63,143,134,88,377,368,517,525,598,887,1356,1902,1594,6248,5839,6902,8214,11394,10922,12725,19211,19209,21287,20332,22705,27783,26943,32659,33490,34314,31284,31028,32825,33632,37139,35997,32044,30553,27526,29065,31232,34804,35423,35247,28798,29093,29993,32364,32318,39665,35776,30714,25379,27386,30855,33181,38110,33058,29999,25865,27126,28912,32001,31014,29716,23475,21875,25245,24903,31687,29668,29276,22776,26042,25427,27287,30510,29148,27443,26055,23857,24691,24056,28123,29953,29593,25651,25744,26684,25838,27771,31203,28815,29453,22709,24039,24075,26152,30719,33289,33031,24878,27213,31420,],
                       color: seriesColors[3]
                    },{
                        name: 'إفريقيا',
                        data: [6,0,3,5,6,12,11,22,7,22,33,84,89,63,67,237,283,243,474,621,717,1136,814,854,828,1113,1183,1281,1029,1003,2196,2385,2300,2027,2333,1913,2021,2866,5084,4112,5372,2828,2900,4074,3066,5195,4351,5302,5109,4515,4206,4777,5353,7427,17398,10052,6881,6942,10395,10612,12491,11626,10248,12072,12093,12953,16469,15294,16975,14763,12064,10704,15526,20069,21222,25685,21820,15279,20928,26634,30742,29310,30521,26723,26479,23060,28239,34345,38883,39636,48036,32190,26093,36557,46168,43126,44566,39691,33093,27771,29710,42593,48087,45761,42397,32323,33546,36850,51142,],
                       color: seriesColors[4]
                    }, {
                        name: 'أوقيانوسيا',
                        data: [2,3,9,15,3,7,4,13,15,16,21,34,41,51,49,80,79,124,127,127,299,532,138,425,375,529,419,580,407,458,257,365,347,287,308,228,181,158,169,127,152,117,32,58,81,45,43,68,59,51,24,27,15,15,20,26,20,10,26,11,17,19,23,25,25,32,20,20,7,23,12,22,10,11,31,16,10,10,14,8,9,15,4,15,5,12,16,11,16,19,8,10,20,8,11,7,5,8,6,2,5,3,9,9,5,12,18,15,14,],
                       color: seriesColors[5]
                    }]
                },
                function(chart){// this function is not working as intended yet 
                        $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
                                serie.legendItem.on('mouseover', function(){
                                    console.log('mouse in');

                                }).on('mouseout', function(){
                                    console.log('mouse out');

                                })
                        });

}                
                );
                function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: pls add more details, logs or images ...

Comment: ok I will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this simplified demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/10tg6r48/

Here is the problem with regexp.

Chrome is dealing with this code but in Firefox we get the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid regexp group
```

Comment: In a regular expression in numberWithCommas function.